# Rotor wave fomulation of quantum mechanics and the associated canonical commutation relations of position and momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, clifford-algebra

I've been trying to determine whether it would be possible to formulate non-relativistic quantum mechanics entirely in the [algebra of physical space (APS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_physical_space) by using rotor waves instead of complex-valued plane waves (as a route to providing geometric interpretations of single-particle quantum systems). The standard formulation of a plane wave (in natural units) is
$$
\psi(\vec{x},t) = e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega t)}
$$
but with this formulation, rather than an imaginary unit, a unit APS bivector is exponentiated:
$$
\psi(\vec{x},t) = e^{\hat{B}(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega t)}
$$
The advantage of such a formulation is that the imaginary unit now has a concrete interpretation as a spin plane. However, this raises the question of what the operators in this formulation would look like. To start off, I decided determining the form of the momentum operator would be a good place to start. We know that plane waves are eigenstates of the momentum operator, so I figured starting by trying to take the geometric derivative of the expression I constructed:
$$
\nabla \psi = \vec{k}\hat{B}e^{\hat{B}(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega t)}
$$
This is an eigenfunction of $\nabla$, but the eigenvalue is not the wavevector. In order to resolve this, I thought of multiplying by $\hat{B}^\dagger$ on the right:
$$
\nabla \psi \hat{B}^\dagger = \vec{k}\hat{B}\psi\hat{B}^\dagger
$$
Considering that $\hat{B}$ is a unit bivector, and therefore also equivalent to the rotor $e^{\frac{1}{2}\pi\hat{B}}$, and the action of the rotor plane wave is always in the same plane as $\hat{B}$, the action of $\hat{B}^\dagger$ should be to undo the rotation of $\hat{B}$, and therefore:
$$
\nabla \psi \hat{B}^\dagger = \vec{k}\psi
$$
This suggests that the operator is not just a momentum operator, but a momentum operator that acts on a specific spin component in the plane of rotation provided by $\hat{B}$. However, I'm not certain an operator of this form is able to preserve the canonical commutation relations given a position operator $\hat{x}\psi = \vec{x}\psi$. I've proceeded to perform a derivation by expanding in coordinates:
\begin{align}
\left[\hat{x}, \hat{p}\right] \psi & = \vec{x} (\nabla \psi \hat{B}^\dagger) - \nabla (\vec{x} \psi) \hat{B}^\dagger \\
& = x^k \sigma_k (\sigma^i \partial_i \psi)\hat{B}^\dagger - \sigma^i \partial_i (x^k \sigma_k \psi) \hat{B}^\dagger \\
& = \left[x^k \sigma_k \sigma^i \partial_i \psi - \sigma^i \partial_i (x^k \sigma_k \psi)\right] \hat{B}^\dagger \\
& = \left[x^k \sigma_k \sigma^i \partial_i \psi - \sigma^i \left((\partial_i x^k) \sigma_k \psi + x^k (\partial_i \sigma_k) \psi + x^k \sigma_k (\partial_i \psi) \right)\right] \hat{B}^\dagger \\
\end{align}

I'm making the assumption that space is flat, and therefore the term $\partial_i \sigma_k= 0$. Also, I'm assuming that $\partial_i x^k = \delta_i^k$:

\begin{align}
\left[\hat{x}, \hat{p}\right] \psi & = \left[x^k \sigma_k \sigma^i \partial_i \psi - \sigma^i \left(\delta_i^k \sigma_k \psi + x^k \sigma_k (\partial_i \psi) \right)\right] \hat{B}^\dagger \\
&= \left[x^k \sigma_k \sigma^i \partial_i \psi - \sigma^i \delta_i^k \sigma_k \psi - \sigma^i x^k \sigma_k \partial_i \psi \right] \hat{B}^\dagger \\
&= \left[x^k \sigma_k \sigma^i \partial_i \psi - x^k \sigma^i \sigma_k \partial_i \psi - \sigma^i \delta_i^k \sigma_k \psi \right] \hat{B}^\dagger \\
&= \left[x^k \left(\sigma_k \sigma^i - \sigma^i \sigma_k\right) \partial_i \psi - \sigma^i \delta_i^k \sigma_k \psi \right] \hat{B}^\dagger 
\end{align}

The grouped terms with $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma^k$ seem to be wedge and dot products:

\begin{align}
\left[\hat{x}, \hat{p}\right] \psi & = \left[x^k \left(\sigma_k \wedge \sigma^i\right) \partial_i \psi - \left(\sigma^i \cdot \sigma_k\right) \psi \right] \hat{B}^\dagger \\
& = \left[\left(\sigma^i \cdot \sigma_k\right) \psi - x^k \left(\sigma_k \wedge \sigma^i\right) \partial_i \psi \right] \hat{B} \\
& = \left(\sigma^i \cdot \sigma_k\right) \psi \hat{B} + x^k \left(\sigma_k \wedge \sigma^i\right) \left(\partial_i \psi\right) \hat{B}^\dagger
\end{align}
The dot product term makes sense because this portion seems to reproduce the canonical commutation relations between position and momentum along the same coordinate. However, there is a wedge product term that remains, and strikingly, it seems to resemble the form I would expect for an angular momentum operator (though I am unsure if this is equivalent to $\vec{x} \wedge \nabla \psi \hat{B}^\dagger$ in general).

My question is: **are the forms for the position and momentum operators correct, or do one or both need to be adjusted to maintain the correct canonical commutation relation?** I assume that the extra term in the commutator indicates something is wrong, and the form of one or both have to change, but I also find it remarkable that a term resembling an angular momentum operator appears.

[edit] I realize that *the problem may be the form of the position operator*: instead of it being the geometric product with the wavefunction ($\hat{x}\psi = \vec{x}\psi$), it might be the symmetric product or some sort of dot product. Exactly which, I'm not sure yet.